# Create a Document to Sign from a Template in DocuSign

Tags: docusignapi

Here is my "project".

I need to download rows from Google Sheets with employee info (name, address, email, phone number, and a few other custom fields) and use this information to fill out a template in DocuSign and send it to the employee for signing. The employee does not need to make any edits, they just have to sign the document.

So in the DocuSign web UI, I've created the template with all my fields.

In the API, I start by creating a new envelope:

```
POST /v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes

{
"templateId": "9e35d343-6942-4756-b7aa-XXXXXXXX",
"templateRoles": [
    {
        "email": "joe.doe@doooeeee.com",
        "name": "Joe Doe",
        "roleName": "employee"
    }
],
"status": "created"
}
```

I successfully create the envelope (I see it in the UI) but it's unclear what my next API move is supposed to be to prefill the template. I've been starring into the API documentation but I just don't get it...

Any hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:** the role name "employee" is reserved and will cause some issues here, by changing to some other name - you can get this working.

We have a [step-by-step code example](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/set-template-tab-values/) showing you how to do exactly this.

The JSON will look something like this:

```
"templateId": "9e35d343-6942-4756-b7aa-XXXXXXXX",
    "templateRoles": [{
        "email": "joe.doe@doooeeee.com",
        "name": "Joe Doe",
        "roleName": "employee",
        "tabs": {
            "checkboxTabs": [{
                "selected": "true",
                "tabLabel": "ckAuthorization"
            }, {
                "selected": "true",
                "tabLabel": "ckAgreement"
            }],
            "listTabs": [{
                "documentId": "1",
                "pageNumber": "1",
                "tabLabel": "list",
                "value": "green"
            }],
            "radioGroupTabs": [{
                "groupName": "radio1",
                "radios": [{
                    "selected": "true",
                    "value": "white"
                }]
            }],
            "textTabs": [{
                "tabLabel": "text",
                "value": "Jabberywocky!"
            }, {

        // .....
```

Comment: Awesome, thx, I will try on Monday and report back my success/failure :)

Comment: I am still a bit lost. I'm getting: The operation failed with an error. [400] A Required field is incomplete. TabId: 8922b185-e317-4658-98b4-31a1536cd869

One thing which is not clear to me is that what kind of "fields" should I be using when creating the template in the web UI. There are:
1) Standard Fields
2) Custom Fields
3) Merge Fields
4) Prefill Tools

When I try creating a Custom field, the document is still sent blank. When I create a field in "Prefill Tools", I get the error above. It'd be fastest if we could jump on a 15 minute call. Pretty sure we'll solve it on the spot.

Comment: No Prefill tools here. You have to have text tabs with the same labels above on your template/envelope.

Comment: Okay, so turns out the roleName = "employee" could be some sort of "reserved word" and document is produced blank. 

BUT when changed to "SignerEmployee", the above code from Inbar works OK and the document is prefilled as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [live example](https://apirequestbuilder.docusign.com/?eg=Set%20template%20tabs) via the API Request Builder.

Note that the API Request Builder can be used to create the SDK code for the example in C#, Java, Node.js, PHP, Python, and Ruby